# how to call php variables outside php tags

Tags: php, mysql, post, global-variables, local-variables

i want to call $query somewhere inside the html and this returns undefined. Even after declaring the variable as GLOBAL i still get that error.

```
<?php
if($query){
echo "Nice";
}
else {
echo "Bad";
}
?>
```

The Full PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Name"])) {
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pwd", "DB");
if (!$con){
die(mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("DB", $con) or die (mysql_error());
$Name = preg_replace ('#[^a-z, 1-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['Name']);
$Slog = preg_replace ('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['Slog']);
$GLOBAL['query'] = mysql_query("INSERT INTO profiles (Name, Slog)
VALUES('$Name', '$Slog')") or die (mysql_error());      
mysql_close($con);
}       
?>
```

Here's the html with php and the $query im calling.

```
<form style="width:100px" action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Name">
<input type="text" name="Slog">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p>
<?php
if($query){
echo "Nice";
}
else {
echo "Bad";
}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: you're not setting the $query variable anywhere.

Comment: he is setting it.  look harder

Comment: Are you sure $_POST["Name"] is sent to the PHP file ?

Answer (score 0):

are your php tags and html file located on the same document? if not. then you need to include  your php file together your html codes. in .php filetype.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**  I see a problem.  you're saying "or die()"  so if there's an error, it will STOP the script.  if you don't want that , then you can echo the error instead of die.  die will stop everything, so then query won't be defined.  specifically, if the query returns false, then the "or die" happens before anything gets assigned to query.

what are you expecting query to be? it's an insert query so it should be true or false.  but it has to be in the same file with the html, and what you posted is clearly not the full html.

first, try adding $con, as the second parameter of your query, eg "insert ....",$con)  then, ensure you're actually getting that name parameter in the post, by adding an else or something.

Comment: It does kive something when the function concerned is inside that php on top, but once removed inside the tags it return error. I'm expecting to get an sql error if there's !$query